# cakePHP one app multiple needs

Tags: cakephp, database-schema, cakephp-2.3

I am dealing with a conceptual issue.

I am writing an app which collects data from various user 
profiles.
Each user profile needs a different set of tables.
profiles do not have common tables.

Apart from collecting the data in the end i should perform some short of analysis on them by correlating data from various profiles.

My plan is to have one db, and use prefixes on tables to separate profiles.
Since I have to support ~20 profiles I will end up with 100+ model/controller classes.

Can I somehow organize them in more manageable way ?

Ps: I am a beginner in Cake. :-)

Comment: You could have a 'ProfileField' model which would store the name and possible values/options for a field, and a 'UserProfileField' model which maps these profile fields to a user, then when you create users you could either assign existing profile fields to it (by creating UserProfileField entries) or create a new profile field and map that one...

Comment: hm.............I think that the best option should be to have a seperate app for each profile. Then I ll have a clean MVC separation for each profile BUT I will end up with many db's (one for each profile)....

Comment: One app per profile is a maintenance horror, worst thing you can do IMHO.

Comment: @gpio I totally disagree. When taking an "MVC" approach means you need potentially endless numbers of tables or databases you're doing something wrong. You ideally want to find out the best way to effectively store and represent your data in a way that minimises your database use, and a mapping relationship like above will achieve that. It's still MVC if that's what you're worried about... User hasMany UserProfileField which hasOne ProfileField. Cake makes these relationships super easy for you to set up and maintain...

Comment: Lets say we do have a 1)farmer 2)computer geek 3)baker 4)journalist and so on. Each user profile needs a special set of forms which end up in a different relational schema. To implement one supper dynamic db schema which can fit in all needs it sounds utopia for me.....

Answer (score 2):

Use a [key-value store](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database), see [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) as well. You can implement that using a single table in a relational DB or you can use a key-value database.

```
profile_id | key | value
```

This simple table layout allows you to store as many key-value pairs per profile as you like.

What DB system you're using for that and how you implement it in CakePHP is up to you.